# Flexbox for centering text in the middle of a bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I have a grid of boxes that vary in size, and one of the boxes has a bootstrap carousel: http://www.bootply.com/129530

Have tried a bunch of combinations for getting the text of the items in the carousel to be vertically aligned in the middle, most specifically the table/table-cell solution..

Someone just recommended using a flexbox.. Would really  appreciate a solution or an example..

```
<div class="box10 border">
  <div class="foo">
    <div id="foo-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="bar">...line of text here...</div>
        </div><!-- /item -->
        <div class="item">
          <div class="bar">...paragraph here...</div>
        </div><!-- /item -->
        <div class="item">
          <div class="bar">...paragraph there...</div>
        </div><!-- /item -->
      </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->
    </div><!-- /carousel -->
  </div><!-- /foo -->
</div><!-- /box10 -->
```

Bootstrap carousel CSS

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

Basic Custom CSS

```
.box10 {
  height:20%;
}
.foo {
  height: 100%;
}
.bar {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
.foo {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This tells the .foo div to use flexbox and to vertically aligns stuff inside.
Add vendor prefixes if needed.